# Mask image with static threshold in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, video, image-processing, morphological-analysis

I need to Binarize an image in matlab with a static threshold of 10% of mean intensity. I find mean intensity using `mean2(Image)` and this returns a mean let say `15.10` in one of the image. Thus my mean threshold is `1.51`.`im2bw(image,level)` takes threshold between 0 to 1. How to binarize my image in this case in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can binarize the image with a simple logical statement. For completeness, I've added the threshold determination as well.

```
threshold = mean(Image(:));

binaryMask = Image > 0.1 * threshold;
```

Comment: I don't think I am getting a binary image. It's lot of colored pixels.Binary should have been B/W right? and btw shouldn't the mean() be mean2() ?

Comment: @Panther: You may first need to convert your image from RGB to grayscale (if `size(Image)` shows a size of 3 in the third dimension) using `rgb2gray`. Also `mean2(x)` is a shortcut for `mean(x(:))`, see the ["algorithm" section in the help](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mean2.html).

Answer (score 3):

1) you can first convert the original image to double format using `im2double()`. Then all the pixels values will be between 0 and 1. Then you can use `im2bw(im,level)`.

2) If you do not want to convert the image to double, then you can do it in this way. Let's say the threshold is 10 % of the the mean value, say `threshold = 1.51`. Let's denote the image you have is `im`. Then `im(im<threshold) = 0; im(im>=threshold)=1`. After these two operations, `im` will become a binary image.

Comment: I did this: `mu=mean2(idiff);
threshold=0.1*mu;
idiff(idiff>=threshold)=1;
idiff(idiff<threshold)=0;
imagesc(idiff);` I get a black image. Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: change the sequence of 'idiff(idiff>=threshold)=1;' and 'idiff(idiff<threshold)=0;' and then show it by using this command 'imshow(im, [])'. If you use 'imshow(im)', you may have a black figure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to normalize the result of the mean vs the max intensity of the image if you want to use `im2bw` (the other solutions mentioned are of course correct and work):

```
ImageN=Image./max(Image(:))
t = mean2(ImageN) * 0.1 % Find your threshold value 
im2bw(Image,t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your image is a matrix `img`, you can do the following:

```
t = mean2(img) * 0.1 % Find your threshold value
img(img < t) = 0 % Set everything below the treshold value to 0
img(img ̃= 0) = 1 % Set the rest to 1
```